# How is related the exponential map, the covariant derivative and the gauge transformations under Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, gauge-invariance

I will try to formulate my question the best way possible considering my lack of mathematical formalism.
I just want to know, in every aspects, why spinors transforms (under Lorentz transformations) the way they do.

\begin{equation}
    \Psi^{\prime}\left(x^{\prime}\right)=S \Psi(x)
\end{equation}

With

\begin{equation}
S=\exp \left(\frac{1}{4} \Omega_{\mu \nu} \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu\right)
\end{equation}

I know that the exponential comes from the exponential map which relates the gauge 1-form and the element of the SO(1,3) Lie algebra with an element of the Group.

My question is why i can write the element over the exponential as a covariant derivative, and (Sorry for the notation) what is exactly the outcome of the following expression:

\begin{equation}
exp(i\nabla_{\mu})
\end{equation}

With

\begin{equation}
\nabla_\mu=\partial_\mu-\frac{1}{2} \omega_\mu^{a b} M_{a b}
\end{equation}

I hope you can understand my question and i will thank any comment or reference about this topic.